# Is a 1" (one inch) sensor camera workable for stock or commercial photography?

Tags: image-quality, sensor-size, stock-photography, commercial-photography

Is it possible to deliver commercially-acceptable results using a 1-inch sensor size camera (let me suggest Sony RX10M4 / Panasonic FZ1000M2 as an example camera here)?

By the commercially-acceptable results I mean quality of the image for both photos and videos and not the composition or any other factors obviously. Will it be accepted by stocks (like Adobe) or these are more like amateur cameras for travel and family photos and videos?

I saw quite controversial opinions here and there online but none of them looks comprehensive enough to me to answer the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use a Nikon 1 V2 with a 1" sensor for commercial work fairly often... mostly product type photography. The image quality has a lot more to do with other factors... and whether it is sufficient or not really depends on the requirements.

I don't sell to stock agencies, but Adobe Stock has a minimum requirement of 4MP for photos and 1920x1080 for video; which is more than adequate for most web based requirements (other agencies are similar). And my Nikon1 can meet/exceed those requirements, so the 1" sensor results should be acceptable.

But actual requirements are not always known... the agency doesn't know the end use(es) when they accept submisions. And the client often doesn't know what they actually need, and wants as much as they can get (for as little as possible). It's not uncommon for a client/customer to insist that they need way more than they actually do, and trying to correct that is usually futile.

The point of all that is to say; yes 1" sensors can be perfectly acceptable, but you will have a wider market if you use something that produces higher spec'd files. I also use a D850...

Answer (score -2):

For occasional photos, a 1 inch sensor is sufficient but if you make really nice holiday tickets for a photo book I would recommend you to switch to another model there are even relatively good cameras around 500€

Comment: You might want to leave these kind of comments as a comment and not as an answer, because this definitely doesn't answer the question. Why is it sufficient for occasional photos and not for a photo book? What problems would you face? What suggestions would you make? etc.

Comment: sry i cant make a koment under the post

Comment: and plese i am new here and just want to help

Comment: Sure and no problem with that. Incomplete answers, or answers that are just expressing your opinion without context are likely to get down-voted. You will have the commenting [privilege](https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) once you reach a reputation score of 50. In the meantime, have a look at the [How do I write a good answer?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) help page. Hope this helps you get started.

Comment: This might not be a great answer but it *is* an answer. We prefer these to be here in the answer space, *not* as comments. (So you did the right thing.)

Comment: I'd like to welcome you with a vote up, but I don't know what "nice holiday tickets" are in this context. The question is asking about commercial stock photography.

Comment: see on this link http://gestyy.com/w6pWlz